# Как правильно связать ссылки в списке?

Tags: c#, двусвязный-список

С указателями на объекты все проще, но вот с ссылками у меня не выходит правильно организовать их связь.

Кусок кода который связывал объекты через указатели:

```
// получили указатель на указатель на первый элемент

AviChunk** ppAppend = &pRoot->Common.First;

for (;;)
{
    AviChunk* pCk = Memory.Instance.CAlloc<AviChunk>();
    if (pCk == null)
    {
        return Result.Generic;
    }

    if (ChunkRead(pCk, pRoot) != 0)
    {
        ChunkClean(pCk);
        Memory.Instance.Free(&pCk);
        break;
    }

    // указали что первым будет `pCk`

    *ppAppend = pCk;

    // разыменовали `ppAppend`, проверили на `null`
    while (*ppAppend != null)
    {
        // Переписали указатель на `ppAppend` на следующий элемент

        ppAppend = &(*ppAppend)->Common.Next;

        // пошли дальше по циклу
    }

   ...
}
```

Но когда я попробовал сделать тоже самое с ссылками:

```
IChunk append = container.First;

for (;;)
{
    if (chunk == null)
    {
        return ReadResult.Generic;
    }

    result = chunk.Read(stream, container);

    if(result != ReadResult.Ok)
    {
        if (result != ReadResult.ZeroSized)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    container.First = chunk;

    while (append != null)
    {
        append = append.Next; // BUG: Need to check!
    }

    ...
}
```

То такое не прокатило.

Подскажите, как правильно связывать списки через ссылки?

Интерфейс списка:

```
public interface IChunk
{
    uint Fcc { get; set; }
    ulong Size { get; set; }
    ulong Position { get; set; }

    IChunk Next { get; set; }
    IChunk Parent { get; set; }
    IChunk First { get; set; }

    ulong End { get; }
    IChunk Find(uint fcc, int number, bool isList);
    T Find<T>(uint fcc, int number, bool isList) where T : IChunk;
    void DumpDebug(int level = 0);

    ReadResult ToNext(Stream stream);
    ReadResult BeginRead();
    ReadResult Read(Stream stream, IChunk parent);
    ReadResult Read(Stream stream);
}
```

Comment: `То такое не прокатило.` как это понимать?

Comment: @tym32167: Нельзя взять ссылку на ссылку, что бы записать по ссылке на ссылку значение.